# Dynamic FIFO presenter for a collection of window-like controls

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, mvvm, fifo

Due to the issues related to the dialog windows going sometimes behind the main application and confusing the users because the dialog is only accessible via ALT+TAB, I'd like to create an dynamic FIFO presenter for a collection of window-like user controls that are embedded in the user interface instead of standalone windows (see: [image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ntdT.png).

- What control would be preferred as itemshost to contain these user controls?
- Any patterns/practices I should prefer?
- Any existing solutions available?

I'd prefer MVVM-applicable solutions but all guidance is golden.

Comment: While the popup dialogs are being displayed, do you want the user to be able with the main window?

Comment: have you tried, dialogBox.showdialog() ?

Comment: @bit Can't think of any situation where users would need to access the main window simultaneously, the user controls contain a border with a rectangle opacity overlay which renders the main window inaccessible.

Comment: @KCdod Yes I have but I don't want to use the native windows in this case, because they are quite ugly and the user experience is generally bad because they are detached from the application.

Comment: You might want to use the Child Window control as base to design your control.. You may stack multiple dialogs/questions and display them to the user one after another and when the user has answered all of them you may close the your control (ChildWindow)

Comment: you can use Form.ShowDialog() too :)

Comment: Reference to the child window control: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-child-window/

Comment: @bit Thanks! I didn't even know that such control exists, I'll definately have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the `ChildWindow` control as base to design your control. 
You may stack multiple dialogs/questions and display them to the user one after another and when the user has answered all of them you may close the your control (`ChildWindow`).

This would also prevent the users from interacting with the `MainWindow`

See [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-child-window/) for more on `ChildWindow`